# django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type double precision: “max”

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I changed the data type of a field "max" in my model from string to float and I got this error when I run python3 manage.py migrate after makemigrations. What's the solution please?

django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "max

```
     my original model:
     class calculation(models.Model):
        fullname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        min = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        max = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        unit = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

     my model after the change::
     class calculation(models.Model):
        fullname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        max = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        unit = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you add your model code please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
class just_model(models.Model):
    field_from_model = models.IntegerField('just a field', 
    validators[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(11)])
```